# Run private Ethereum blockchain without the need for gas

Tags: ethereum, web3js, metamask, go-ethereum

I try to run an Ethereum Blockchain using geth for deploying and using contracts. It's a private blockchain, and I have no use for miners or gas. No ether should be distributed, and the participants should be able to deploy and use contracts without Ether in their accounts.

I found [How can I send transaction with no gas fee on private chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57422470/how-can-i-send-transaction-with-no-gas-fee-on-private-chain) and tried my luck with --miner.gasprice 0. But I still get 'insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction'.

How to completely remove gas price?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove gas, because it is needed as internal unit of account for EVM.

If you need to run a private blockchain without any kind of internal accounting of used resources, I suggest you look non-EVM based alternatives like Oracle Blockchain.